# Oracle SQL help counting the same thing two different ways, but with common grouping

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that contains for each entry an `incident_id`, `status` (Let's say either `open` or `closed`, `date_raised` (Date) and `closure_date` (Date).

I want to show a table that counts the number of incidents closed on a closure date (so the count of `incident_id` where `status='closed' and closure_date is not null`), and the number of incidents that remain open (count of `incident_id` where `status='open'` on that same day.

In case I've confused you, a table that looks like this:

```
 ______________________________________________________________________________
| closure date | count of incidents closed | count of incidents remaining open |
|--------------|---------------------------|-----------------------------------|
| 01-Sep-12    | 5                         | 14                                |
| ...          | ...                       | ...                               |
```

I've managed a table that does the count of incidents closed like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(incident_id)
WHERE closure_date IS NOT NULL AND status="open"
GROUP BY closure_date
```

I've tried for hours now to get the other count working, but can't so far :-(

Edit: Here is an example of the table I have:

```
 ___________________________________________________
| incident_id | status | date_raised | closure_date |
|-------------|--------|-------------|--------------|
| 1           | closed | 01-Sep-12   | 01-Sep-12    |
| 2           | open   | 30-Aug-12   | (null)       |
| 3           | open   | 02-Sep-12   | (null)       |
| 4           | closed | 02-Sep-12   | 05-Sep-12    |
| ...         | ...    | ...         | ...          |
```

Would give the table:

```
 ______________________________________________________________________________
| closure date | count of incidents closed | count of incidents remaining open |
|--------------|---------------------------|-----------------------------------|
| 01-Sep-12    | 1                         | 1                                 |
| 05-Sep-12    | 1                         | 2                                 |
```

Comment: hmmm, in fact not that clear, maybe : what's the primary key of your table ? incident_id ? means that an incident can't have two status ? Or ? Maybe the real table structure or some sample datas could help...

Comment: @Raphael incident_id is the primary key. The table has incident_id, date_raised, closure_date and status. Therefore if the status is open, the closure date will be null. If the status is closed, there will be a closure date. The solutions below do not show the number of open incidents on or before the given closure date, but do show the number of closures on the closure date

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I've added an example table of my data in the question

Comment: Ok, edited my answer, should work better.

Comment: By the way, I removed the `closure_date is not null` test, as I think a "closed" status means a closure_date is not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that for each date, you want to get the number of issues that have been closed to date as well as the number of issues still open that were raised *before* that date, correct? So you might want something like this:

```
SELECT t1.closure_date, COUNT(t1.incident_id)
     , ( SELECT COUNT(t2.incident_id) FROM incident_table t2
          WHERE t2.status = 'open'
            AND t2.raised_date < t1.closure_date )
  FROM incident_table t1
 WHERE t1.closure_date IS NOT NULL
   AND t1.status = 'closed'
 GROUP BY t1.closure_date
```

Comment: I will as soon as I get to 15 rep! :P

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) as closed,
(SELECT COUNT(t2.incident_id) FROM TABLE t2 WHERE t2.status = 'open' and t2.raised_date < t1.closure_date) as open
FROM TABLE t1
WHERE 
t1.status = 'closed'
GROUP BY t1.closure_date
```

or same idea

```
WITH opened AS (SELECT COUNT(t2.incident_id) as cnt FROM table t2 WHERE STATUS = 'open' )
SELECT 
   to_char(closure_date, 'yyyy/mm/dd') as dte
   count(*) as closed,
   opened.cnt as opens
FROM table, opened
WHERE status = 'closed'
GROUP BY to_char(closure_date, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), opened.cnt
```

Comment: It's close, but the open count needs not only the `status = 'open'`, but also somehow `date_raised < [the closure_date of the group]` I don't know if this is possible :-S

Comment: @BenHill, yes. Done. Oh well, burned ;)

Comment: Unlucky, you got beaten to it! ;-) Got close though!

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

```
SELECT 
closure_date,
SUM(CASE WHEN status="open" 
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "count of incidents open",
SUM(CASE WHEN  status="closed" 
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "count of incidents closed"
FROM YourTable
WHERE closure_date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY closure_date
```